# Unable to generate google maps API code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to create API code for google maps but it won't work. I'm signed into my google account, I started with "get a key" "create new" and only get message "couldn't create project" Ive tried different browsers as well... same result. No help from google unless you have paid account.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a project in **[Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_backend,geocoding_backend,directions_backend,distance_matrix_backend,elevation_backend,places_backend&reusekey=true)** using your Google account.

If the problem still persists, do these following steps:

1. File an issue at **[Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)**. You don't need to have a paid account for this.
2. Select the appropriate component, normally, just like this: **Public Trackers > Google Maps APIs > Javascript3**
3. In the description. make sure to give enough details so they can handle your issue immediately. Ambiguous description may result for further clarifications.

> Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.

You can learn more about Issue Tracker through this **[link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)**.

Hope it helps!